# Postgres list only user's database and keep other hidden?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I've created a postgres user 'tester' and allowed to readonly to a database **A**. This user has no permisssion on database **B** & **C**.

But when I do `\l` to list database. The database **B** and **C** are also listed. How can I only list database **A** and keep other databases hidden?

I'm facing this in pgadmin. I cannot edit in pgadmin. I need a way to hide those other database using access policy in postgres db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do that in PostgreSQL. Don't try to modify permissions on catalog tables, that is likely to break PostgreSQL, and will certainly break client tools like pgAdmin and `psql`.

Comment: Thanks for answering :)